# Ajax on Add another item of field collection

Tags: 7, javascript, ajax, entities

I'm calling an Ajax function in a field collection. But after hitting 'Add another item' button, form looses Ajax effect. I want to bind the Ajax with form event after clicking on 'Add another item' button. Can anyone help?

Comment: I am also having this problem. I was able to do this with the beta4 release but something has changed with beta5.

Comment: Actually we solved this problem with form_alter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually on reload of page Ajax looses its effect. So we solved this problem through form alter.

`$form['#after_build']` gives us all the detail after save so that helps to retrieve values again and filter.

Comment: can you edit with all the code?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to use [Drupal.behaviors](http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) and not just document.ready for your javascript.

> Drupal uses a "behaviors" system to provide a single mechanism for
>   attaching JavaScript functionality to elements on a page. The benefit
>   of having a single place for the behaviors is that they can be applied
>   consistently when the page is first loaded and then when new content
>   is added during AHAH/AJAX requests.

More info on Drupal.behaviors [here](http://drupal.org/node/171213#behaviors)

Comment: thanks for reply...actually while writing my js and ajax i have already used Drupal.behaviors but still its loosing the effect of ajax on page load